# Window iconification status via Xlib

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

Is it possible to check **with the means of pure X11/Xlib only** whether the given window is iconified/minimized, and, if it is, how?

Answer (score 2):

yes. there are several ways of doing it:

- read the _NET_WM_STATE property and check its content (as described in 'http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2507241'). for code, how to do this see some windowmanagers ([fluxbox](http://git.fluxbox.org/?p=fluxbox.git;a=blob;f=src/Ewmh.cc;h=fb1b832522e4db47b2e119849822a07e27410495;hb=HEAD) or [pekwm](http://pekwm.org/projects/pekwm/repository/browse?path=src/Atoms.cc) comes to mind)
- read the WM_STATE property and check its content (as described in http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.1.3.1).

Answer (score -1):

[`XGetWMHints()`](http://www.tigr.net/afterstep/X/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetWMHints.html) seems to be the preferred way of doing it.

There's also the function `XGetZoomHints()`, but that seems to have been deprecated.

Comment: That was not quite the thing I needed (if I am right, XGetWMHints() only allows to check window's **initial**, not current parameters). So, after some stressed thinking, I came up with this, should work at least under most circumstances: http://pastebin.com/f356a8010

Comment: I would suggest trying it and comparing it to its unmapped state. Also try checking its zoom state. I'm no X11 expert, so I don't know which is the most reliable. Do remember that different window managers handle iconification differently.